# tablet POS system

Tags: html, tablet, point-of-sale

I have a project to create a point of sale system, which in each table in a restaurant will have a tablet. The idea is this tablet will communicate to the kitchen interface and send customer's order directly to the kitchen. I'm planning to use HTML 5 and phonegap for the tablet.

My question is:

1. How can I connect each tablet to the kitchen interface? is it possible to send information over the wifi? Do I need a hub or router?
2. I have seen API such as e-thor and square register, can I use those API to build this system?
3. Is it possible to customize the tablet so it can only open the app?

Thanks, any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. how can I connect each tablet to the kitchen interface? is it possible to send information over the wifi? Do I need a hub or router?

Yes, a hub such as a linksys router with each tablet connected wirelessly to the same SSID on the router will allow you to talk to the internet or the intranet for your kitchen service.

> 2. I have seen API such as e-thor and square register, can I use those API to build this system?

Yes, a webapp utilizing the apis for this system will receive orders from people and allow them to pay for them as well (given they have the ability to swipe their cards with a square for example). The hardest part to your question is the webapp and how it will store and use the information from users. This is the part that you need to think about as the rest of your questions are trivial.

> 3. Is it possible to customize the tablet so it can only open the app?

Yes, many apps do this and it is usually in parental controls or administration of users for the tablet (depending on the operating system).